# Extension Point in Obeo Uml-Designer Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml-designer

Is it possible to display Extension Points in Use Case compartment in Obeo Uml-Designer Use Case Diagram ?

Answer (score 0):

No, extension points are not supported.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22443560)

Comment: @georgeawg - this doesn't seem to be a link-only answer as it is self-contained and does in fact answer the question, albeit in a very brief way. For further discussion see [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/3744182) - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22443560)